# Printing rdbuf() to console works, but getline fails

Tags: c++

I'm having a strange issue where printing to the console using rdbuf() from a file using ifstream works, but the string parameter inside of getline never returns a value, and thus fails to print to the console in a for loop. I was trying to add the lines in the file to a vector for processing and I know there's other methods to do that, but I'm confused as to why the getline would fail. The file consists of the following text:

One 
Two
Three
Four

Code below.

```
    std::string path = "C:/testfile.txt";      

    std::ifstream File(path);
    File.open(path);
    std::string placeholder;

    if (!File.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "WARNING: Unable to open file" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        //This prints to the console correctly;
        std::filebuf* stream = File.rdbuf();
        std::cout << stream << std::endl;
        //------------------------------------

        //This fails because placeholder is always "" and the loop doesn't run.
        for (std::string output; std::getline(File, placeholder);) 
        {
            std::cout << output << std::endl;
        }

        File.close();
    }
```

Comment: You code fails because you have exhausted the buffer for the stream `File`, its at the end of the file and there's nothing more to read.

Comment: That's strange, I don't think I understand why that would be at the end of the file when the for loop is beginning to run. Even if I remove the first two lines in the else condition the console still comes up blank and debugger skips over the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.rdbuf()` doesn't return a copy of the buffer for the stream, it returns a pointer to the actual in-use buffer for the stream.

That means when you do

```
 std::cout << stream << std::endl;
```

you exhaust the actual file stream, and put it at the end of file. Which means the `std::getline` call will fail.

You need to reset the stream and seek back to the beginning again after the output.

---

The problem with opening the file twice is that the second attempt will *fail*, meaning that `failbit` will be set. And that means all future operations on the stream itself (but not the buffer) will fail.

See e.g. [this `open` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) for details.

The obvious solution is of course to not open the file twice, but if there's a risk that it might happen then always `clear` the stream status after calling `open`.

Comment: I removed the following lines
std::filebuf* stream = File.rdbuf();
std::cout << stream << std::endl;
It still failed. Then after some research I added 
File.clear();
File.seekg(0);
The get line finally worked. Why would the file buffer be at the end of the file at the point of the for loop in this situation?

Comment: @AngryDev With the code you show, if you comment out the `std::cout << stream << std::endl;` line, then it should work fine. Are you doing something you don't show in your actual code? Is the code you show a proper [mcve]?

Comment: You were right, the culprit was File.Open(path), it was setting the buffer at the very end of the file. When I removed File.Open(path), I removed File.clear(); and File.seekg(0), everything is now working as intended with no extra fluff. I hadn't realized std::ifstream File(path) was already opening the file.

Comment: @AngryDev Updated answer with the reason for the `open` call causing your code to fail.